# Getting Access denied if call API without call the official website

Tags: java, api

I'm Benjamin, currently study in IT and doing a simple application for Final Year Project.
The simple application is calling Third Party API (An fashion products company) and returns product description, stock level and etc to users.

First, I don't have any official API documents and everything starts from scratch.

I have been using java - CloseableHttpClient to call an API with the method GET.
Coding works fine BUT I met an error that "no response" or Access Denied if I tried to call the API directly. (without any cookies or with existing cookies from the official website)

Then I tried with a browser(any) to hit the API link, it will return Access Denied
But when I tried with a browser and hit the official website without any login, and hit again the API then able to get responses.

I have been tried to passing the cookies that returned from the official website but still no responses when I call/hit the API link on java code or Postman.

Answer for why calling an API that doesn't have any official documentation as below:
This is an FYP in University, API is selected and provided by University Lecturer.

My code as below :

```
                      CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                                  .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStoreNew)
                                  .setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0").build();
                          HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
                          getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
                          getRequest.addHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0");
                          getRequest.setConfig(requestConfig);
                          System.out.println("this is get request config : \n"+getRequest);
                          System.out.println("\n start execute");
                          HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);//it will stucked here and no reponses
                          System.out.println("\n end execute");
                          if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                              throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                                 + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                          }
```

Please comment below if you have any idea or any advice and Appreciate your help.

This is not spoon feed, I have been researched for over 2 weeks.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have worked in such scenarios like yours when the written code needs to make any HTTP request to an API (third party).

As far as my experience says, there should be some issue of Authentication for your code.
As you said hitting the same API on browser also says "Access denied", some login credentials must be required by API with the GET request you are sending, so when creds are not found, API responds with "Access Denied"..

Could you check the http status code your getting in postman while you are hitting the API, it must be 401/403(Unauthorized).

if in postman http status code is 401/403 indeed, then Kindly ask your University Lecturer for any logins that might be required to hit the API.

Comment: Hi Naman, Thanks for your reply. Yes, I'm getting 403 when hitting API by browser, but when trying in Postman it's sending and no response (same as my java code). And yes, did discuss with University Lecture but the answer is "this is one of the parts he wants me to solve". Question: can we "guess" the login credential or any auth credential that the API needs? Thanks

Comment: @Ben Lim: There are no login credentials.  You said in your question, "when I tried with a browser and hit the official website without any login, and hit again the API then able to get responses.'  That means that some cookie is set by the official website, and I'm guessing your lecturer wants you to figure out how to create the cookie in your code.  Worst case, hit the official website in your code and see what response you get.